# getting ID of anchor tag and put it inside laravel 4.2 session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

hello i have these set of div where the user clicks an anchor tag inside it and that anchor tag has an id. I needed to get that id and use it do display records in a modal in the same so far here is my code

the anchor tag

```
<a id="{{$num}}" class="modal-trigger z-depth-1 btn dgray " onclick="cModal(this.id);" href="{{ URL::to('#modFile')}}">
```

this anchor tag calls a function to get its id and here is it

```
       function cModal(id)
       {
        alert(id);

        <?php $val = "<script>var x = id;</script>"; ?>
        {{ Session::put('NID' , $val) }}
       }
```

see what im trying to do here is create a laravel session inside and put the acquired id inside but the problem is the id is a javascript variable. any ideas on how i can get that id and put it inside a session? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
The anchor is a variable only visible on client side, there is no way to get it seen by server

Comment: would it be possible if i used a div instead?

Comment: Not sure to understand what "used a div" means, but you simply can't.